# Create File image from external images URL on onCreateNode

Tags: gatsby

I am try to create a File to use images sourced from external image URLs but I am not able to do it correctly, because running gatsby develop always give me this error:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat '.cache\caches\default-site-plugin\tmp-1e3da4727bb3ae064a6cf091adc0ab46.jpg'
at lstatSync (node:fs:1514:3)
at rimrafSync (node:internal/fs/rimraf:180:13)
at Object.rmSync (node:fs:1214:10)
at Object.removeSync (\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\remove\index.js:15:28)
at WriteStream. (\node_modules\gatsby-core-utils\dist\fetch-remote-file.js:122:26)
at WriteStream.emit (node:events:402:35)
at finish (node:internal/streams/writable:750:10)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
errno: -4048,
syscall: 'lstat',
code: 'EPERM',
path: '****\.cache\caches\default-site-plugin\tmp-1e3da4727bb3ae064a6cf091adc0ab46.jpg'
}
```

I am doing it for two different fields, a string and an array of string. I am able to correctly create File node with the single string, but with array of string I have some issues.

Single string:

```
exports.onCreateNode = async ({
  node,
  actions: { createNode, createNodeField },
  createNodeId,
  cache,
  store,
}) => {
  // Single string
  if (node.internal.type === 'MyType') {
    const fileNodeImageMap = await createRemoteFileNode({
      url: node.imageLink,
      parentNodeId: node.id,
      createNode,
      createNodeId,
      cache,
      store,
    });

    if (fileNodeImageMap) {
      createNodeField({ node, name: 'imageLinkFile', value: fileNodeImageMap.id });
    }
  }
};
```

Array of string:

```
exports.onCreateNode = async ({
  node,
  actions: { createNode, createNodeField },
  createNodeId,
  cache,
  store,
}) => {
  // Single string
  if (node.internal.type === 'MyType') {
    // Array of string
    const links = node.additionalImageLink.split(',');
    const additionalImages = links.map(async (d) => {
      const fileNodeImage = await createRemoteFileNode({
        url: d,
        parentNodeId: node.id,
        createNode,
        createNodeId,
        cache,
        store,
      });

      if (fileNodeImage) {
        return fileNodeImage.id;
      }
    });

    if (additionalImages.length > 0) {
      const responses = await Promise.all(additionalImages);
      const additionalId = responses.map((d) => d.id);
      createNodeField({ node, name: 'additionalImageLinkFile', value: additionalId });
    }
  }
};
```

Can you point me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

What I have already tried:

- gatbsy clean
- remove node_modules
- remove yarn.lock
- yarn install

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-architecture-r26oq?file=/gatsby-node.js) you can find a minimal reproduction codesanbox.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox? It's difficult to guess what's wrong without debugging there

Comment: @FerranBuireu if you have an idea how I can generate around 300 links to images, yes. If I use https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080 is it going to cache all them after the first one, right? However I think issue is a timeout. Because if I use only the same link with `const links = new Array(4).fill(MyLinkImage');` all going to work.

Comment: @FerranBuireu I tried with random image, with caching and without caching. If I use `https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080` images are going to be cached and I am able to start dev mode. Without images caching and using `https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080${Math.random()}` I get the same error as before. I am pretty sure it is a timeout issue. I have only 300 images, is it a problem?

Comment: It will rely on your connection. Have you tried `GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD=15 gatsby develop` in your develop command? Just to check if it changes

Comment: @FerranBuireu I was also finaly able to provide you a working codesanbox. You can find it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-architecture-r26oq?file=/gatsby-node.js. By the way, I do not the same error, but just a `source and transform nodesKilled` and `error Command failed with exit code 137.` With `GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD=15 gatsby develop` I have the same error.

Comment: It seems to be reaching the memory limit...

Comment: @FerranBuireu On codesanbox for sure.

Comment: @FerranBuireu Setting some env variable to `GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD=1,
GATSBY_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=200000 and GATSBY_STALL_TIMEOUT=200000` I am now able to start dev mode for the first time. I think the issue (maybe a bug?) is related to a try to remove an element (a tmp image) not present (not fully download).